# How to use invokeChaincode() API

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I want to invoke another chaincode in the same channel, but I don't know how to use the InvokeChainCode API. I tried to test it, but got some err.

```
INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: transaction ID:: cannot retrieve package for chaincode dealercc/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/dealercc.1.0: no such file or directory"
```

And, I search online but find nothing, but I find this from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/chaincodenamespace.html#considerations

> For chaincode to chaincode interactions using the invokeChaincode() API, both chaincodes must be installed on the same peer.

However, I am not sure what it means. Does he want me to install all the chaincodes on the peer which use ICC API? if he does, what should i do? I tried but got err, saying something had already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke one chaincode from another chaincode, you need to make sure that
that both chaincodes are installed on each endorsing peer, after that you can do chaincode to chaincode invocation.

Chaincode to chaincode invocation be pretty straight forward, here is an example:

```
// Invoke
func (am *accountManagement) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) 
peer.Response {
actionName, params := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

if actionName == "callAnotherCC" {
    chainCodeArgs := util.ToChaincodeArgs("anotherCCFunc", "paramA")
    response := stub.InvokeChaincode("anotherCCName", chainCodeArgs, "channelName")

    if response.Status != shim.OK {
       return shim.Error(response.Message)
    }
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// NOTE: This is an example, hence assuming only valid call is to call another chaincode
return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] No <%s> action defined", actionName))
}
```

This example is from the implementation of previous shim library, you can update this according to the latest shim library

Comment: I know how to code it, but my system got err.. does it has any conditions before use it?

Comment: check if both the chaincodes are installed on the same endorsing peer

Comment: sorry but do you mean both chaincodes should install on the same peer? I installed sell's on the sell peers, and dealer do so

Comment: yes, both chaincodes must be installed on each endorsing peer

Comment: Sorry but could you give me a further instruction, plz. My English is not very good.. I mean, I have installed ORG3's chaincode on ORG3's peer, and ORG2's chaincode on ORG2's peer, do you mean i should install ORG2's chaincode ont ORG3's peer, too?

Comment: THANK U!!!! I make it!!! it do needs all the chaincodes to be installed, and i mistaked what -n mean. Thank you for your kind instruction!!